# Where do you write campaign code for redirects? .htaccess or index.html

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, utm

I'm fairly new to .htaccess and proper re-directs.  I recently bought domain.net and want to redirect to domain.com, but I want to track the traffic via Google Analytics campaign.

Would I put the UTM code in index.html?  Should I do it somehow in .htaccess?

Sorry, I'm just a little new to this aspect.
I've researched how to track redirect traffic from domain.net to domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following code into a .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1?utm_source=domain.net&utm_medium=redirect [NE,L,R=301]
```

Of course you have to replace the domains in this example.
If you search for "htaccess redirect google analytics" you will found some other solutions in the web too.

Comment: Thank you Timo, I'll give it a shot.